# How to divide a dataset into partitions and store different attributs of a specific function?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr, store

in this example I would like to use just one column of a data.frame: 
My selected column should be divided in partitions every 70 rows. 
 
For example: 1..70 / 71...140 / 141...210 up to N=65.000 
**Output:** On every subset, specific functionalities should store different attributes.

In this special case I would like to store $MSE and $ME from the verfiy-function of the verification-package. To underline this process again:

- All I want is to go over my column every 70 rows;
- use the verify-function;
- and store some attributes in a new data.frame

.

```
ID.            MSE.         ME. 
1 (1to70)      0.3          0.6   
2 (71to140)    0.2          0.5
3 (141to210)   0.25         0.76
...            ...          ...
```

I have tried the following, but I can't handle how to store my attributes per partition as explained above.

```
set.seed(1) # reproducible data
df <- as.data.frame(runif(65000,0,1))
probabilities.to.check.against <- runif(70,0,1)

store.as.df <- df[1] %>% 
    mutate(ID = floor((row_number()-1)/70)) %>%   # I'm trying to select partitions every 70 rows
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    verify(probabilities.to.check.against, PARTIOTIONS_OF_DF, frcst.type = "cont", obs.type = "cont")
```

Comment: I think you should explore how to work with list columns in a data.frame...using nest() function from tidyverse...I think the function is in dplyr or tidyr package

Comment: @ira01 please post example data (`df`?)

Comment: @PoGibas: I have added an example :)

Comment: @ira ID is a character column with parenthesis?

Comment: @PoGibas No it's not. Just a new column to group my partitions. So my first partition is from row 1 to row 70 and become ID 1 and so on. "ID" is just the col. name and the values are numeric

Comment: But I'm also appreciate for alternative solutions on this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
# split your data
runs <- 70
sdf <- split(df, 0:(nrow(df)-1) %/% runs)

# Validate split
library(purrr)
head(map_dbl(sdf, ~nrow(.x)))
#  0  1  2  3  4  5 
# 70 70 70 70 70 70

# Answer
ans <- map_df(sdf, ~as.data.frame(verify(probabilities.to.check.against, .x[,1], frcst.type = "cont", obs.type = "cont")[c("MSE","ME")]), .id="id")

# Output
     # id       MSE            ME
# 1     0 0.1326722  5.145940e-03
# 2     1 0.1662103 -3.211852e-02
# 3     2 0.1522823  1.594105e-02
# 4     3 0.1485422 -1.069273e-01
# 5     4 0.1714966  1.595200e-03
# 6     5 0.2195108  1.866164e-03
# 7     6 0.1942890 -1.029523e-02
# 8     7 0.1730359  4.800538e-04
# 9     8 0.1432483  1.843559e-02
# 10    9 0.1554882 -6.644684e-03
# 11   10 0.1895140 -3.035421e-02
# # etc
```

Change `id` if you want to the format you specify with

```
ans$id <- c(paste0(head(as.numeric(ans$id),-1)*runs+1, "-", tail(as.numeric(ans$id),-1)*runs), tail(as.numeric(ans$id),1)*runs+1)
# [1] "1-70"        "71-140"      "141-210"     "211-280"     "281-350"
```

Comment: It's working amazing! Perfect! Thank you very much :)